# Twitter Typehead.JS - Custom div with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I want to create a custom typehead.JS with AJAX call.

So, What I have done-

JS-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var data = {
            "places":[
                {
                "value":"Abal",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Abal Car",
                "label":"an Abal"
                },
                {
                "value":"Audi",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Audi car",
                "label":"an Audi"
                },
                {
                "value":"BMW",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"BMW car",
                "label":"a BMW"
                },
                {
                "value":"Bugatti",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Bugatti car",
                "label":"a Bugatti"
                },
                {
                "value":"Ferrari",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Ferrari car",
                "label":"a Ferrari"
                }
                ,{
                "value":"Ford",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Ford car",
                "label":"a Ford"
                },
                {
                "value":"Lamborghini",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Lamborghini car",
                "label":"a Lamborghini"
                },
                {
                "value":"Mercedes Benz",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Mercedes Benz",
                "label":"a Mercedes Benz"
                }
                ,{
                "value":"Porsche",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Porsche car",
                "label":"a Porsche"
                }
                ,{
                "value":"Rolls-Royce",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Rolls-Royce car",
                "label":"a Rolls-Royce"
                }
                ,{
                "value":"Volkswagen",
                "image":"http://lorempixel.com/100/100/transport/",
                "description":"Volkswagen car",
                "label":"a Volkswagen"
                }
            ]
        };


    var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: $.map(data.places, function(d) {
        return {value:d.value, suggest:d}
        })
    });

    suggestions.initialize();


    $("#typehead").typeahead(
    {
        minLength: 1,
        hint: true,
        highlight: true
    },
    {
        name: "suggestions",
        displayKey: "value",
        templates: {
                        suggestion: function(data)
                        {
                        //End - Update the data*************************************************************************************************************************************************
                            console.log(data);
                            var details =
                                '<div class=resultContainer>'
                                +data.value
                                +'<div class=resultImage><img src='
                                +data.suggest.image+' /></div><div class=resultDesc>'
                                +data.suggest.description
                                +'</div><div class=resultLabel>'
                                +data.suggest.label
                                +'</div></div>';
                            return details;
                        }
                    },
        source: suggestions.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```

And HTML-

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="typehead"  class="form-control input_black_background slider_top_seperator" name="desired_place" value="" placeholder="Address or City">
</div>
```

So What I am getting is like this-
[image: 1]

But data is not coming from AJAX, it comes from local.

But I want it to be ajax data.

Is there any solution?
I have searched many times in many place for it's solution, but can't find solution.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get this data with an Ajax call you need a URL which will responds with these data on your server. For exemple: `GET /places`

Once you know the URL you need to get these data, you can create a Ajax call to this URL. 
Then instead of using your local data object, you will use ther request' response.

```
$( "#typehead" ).change(function() {
    $.get({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/places' //replace with your real URL
}).success(function (data) {
    var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: $.map(data.places, function(d) {
            return {value:d.value, suggest:d}
        })
    });

    suggestions.initialize();


    $("#typehead").typeahead(
        {
            minLength: 1,
            hint: true,
            highlight: true
        },
        {
            name: "suggestions",
            displayKey: "value",
            templates: {
                suggestion: function(data)
                {
                    //End - Update the data*************************************************************************************************************************************************
                    console.log(data);
                    var details =
                        '<div class=resultContainer>'
                        +data.value
                        +'<div class=resultImage><img src='
                        +data.suggest.image+' /></div><div class=resultDesc>'
                        +data.suggest.description
                        +'</div><div class=resultLabel>'
                        +data.suggest.label
                        +'</div></div>';
                    return details;
                }
            },
            source: suggestions.ttAdapter()
        });
})

};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.

So I have voted it, but it is not working.

Can you please help?

Comment: What is not working ? Does any messages display in the console ?

And you may change `$('.target')` to `$('#typehead')`

Answer (score 0):

first your question is ambiguous, simply use $.getJSON()  in templates object